# How to display video on opengl texture with Gstreamer

Tags: opengl, video-streaming, cross-platform, gstreamer

I want OpenGL texture to display video using gstreamer. Clutter is not an option. Is there any possibility to use plain OpenGl to solve my problem.

My requirement is to have a plateform independent video playback solution and I think gstreamer and OpenGL can be used together as a solution.

Comment: Did you tried to search "gstreamer opengl"? I've got a lot of information to investigate. Here you have to ask only if you can't get something to work, not a suggestion for library or some tutorial.

Comment: Yes and I know there is a gstreamer opengl plugin available but no sample code to start with